# Execution Order in Shiny/Leaflet Click Events

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I have a shiny app which contains a leaflet map. Some code should be executed when I click on the map and some additional code when I click on a polygon.

```
## load data
library(maps)
mapStates = map("state", fill = TRUE, plot = FALSE)

## shiny app
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("map")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(data = mapStates) %>% addTiles() %>%
      addPolygons(fillColor = topo.colors(10, alpha = NULL))
  })

  ## Block 1
  observe({
    input$map_click
    print("Block 1 executed")
  })

  ## Block 2
  observe({
    input$map_shape_click
    print("Block 2 executed")
  })

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

If I click on any shape (polygon) on the map , Block 1 and Block 2 are executed (as expected). However, Block 2 is always executed **before** Block 1. It seems like `input$map_click` and `inpt$map_shape_click` are always updated in a certain order.

I have the following two questions:

1. Why is Block 2 executed first?
2. Can I force Block 2 to be executed after Block 1?

Comment: You can set the `priority` value for different `observe` blocks. An observer with a higher priority value will execute before all observers with lower priority values.

Comment: Your solution works perfectly fine.